# Did this character die in Season 6, episode 3, "Thank You"?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In Season 6 episode 3 it appears that

> Glenn dies. We see what appears to be his guts being ripped out by walkers.

Is this character really dead or is it in fact the body of Nicholas that is being eaten and

> Glenn

is still alive?

Comment: Glenn's path is *WAY* different in the comic.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - The answer has nothing to do with the comics, and the question won't be answered onscreen until episode 7.

Comment: Pro Tip:  When you're talking about a show that has produced a fansite called "The Spoiling Dead Fans", almost nothing is unknown about whichever season is currently being filmed.

Comment: The title of this question sucks. I understand why not explicitly name the character, but this doesn't change the fact titles of the kind "why does THIS character do THAT" are the bane of this website. Therefore, I've changed the title to at least reflect the specific episode it's meant to discuss, so that at least it becomes *partially* useful. Also, -1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Final Update:

> The main thrust of this answer was confirmed to be accurate at the start of Season 6, Episode 7.  Glenn is alive and well. He slid under the dumpster while the zombies ate Nicholas, and crawled out when they dispersed.  Enid was there when he emerged.

---

---

### *Warning - This entire answer is one huge pile of spoilers.  However, the spoilers are limited to the question at hand.  The further you read, the bigger the spoilers become.*

---

## Circumstantial Evidence:

#### The strange way this was handled:

> This "death" has been handled differently than every previous death on the show.  Normally, when a character dies, the actor who played them waits until the episode airs, then goes on social media to say how awesome it was to work with the cast and crew, etc.  Yeun has been absolutely silent on social media.  They also appear on *Talking Dead* that night, and are featured prominently in the "In Memoriam" segment.  Neither of these things happened.

#### Hints at ComicCon:

> At ComicCon this summer, the actors did a Q&A panel, at which they were asked which dead character they would most want to see brought back. Norman Reedus, who plays Daryl, [said "Glenn"](http://www.inquisitr.com/2245133/norman-reedus-jokes-about-death-of-glenn-and-michonne-says-hes-kissed-everyone-on-walking-dead-set/).  **There are two possible explanations for this**:

Option #1:

> Glenn really did die in episode 3, and Reedus was deliberately ruining a huge surprise in front of thousands of fans.

Option #2:

> Glenn didn't die in episode 3, and Reedus was either just being silly for the sake of silliness, or he was teasing the big issue ahead of time, perhaps because he thought that, when episode 3 aired, more people would believe that Glenn really died because Reedus had already hinted at it.

#### Implications of the "death" scene being real:

> It certainly looked like there were enough zombies involved in the attack to eat their victim(s) completely.  This would mean that a major character who has been around since the very first episode of the show would have died without leaving a trace.  No one else would ever know what happened to him;  he would simply have disappeared forever.  There is just no way that the show would do this.  When major characters die, we either see them dying, and their death is so obvious that there is no room for doubt, or we see them reanimate as zombies.  They don't just vanish (from the perspectives of the other characters).

#### Conclusion based on circumstantial evidence:

> Option #2 is clearly far more likely, and the fact that Yeun has remained silent on social media supports the idea that there is more going on here than meets the eye.  The implications of the death being real are also highly problematic, to say the least.  All the circumstantial evidence points to the conclusion that Glenn is alive.

---

## Clear Cut Evidence:

> The actor who plays Glenn, Steven Yeun, been seen filming episodes that haven't aired yet. He was missing from the set during filming of episodes 4, 5, and 6, but he has been on set every episode from 7 to the present (I believe they're filming episode 14 now).  If he was simply filming flashback scenes, he wouldn't have been around every day.  He was around every day, so he must have been filming regular scenes.

And:

> When filming began for episode 7, it was located at the spot where the apparent "death scene" took place, next to the dumpster. Witnesses reported seeing Glenn running down an alley screaming "Enid!" They also said that the dumpster itself isn't a normal one. It has been elevated a few inches off the ground with legs welded onto the bottom, and these modifications apparently made it high enough off the ground that a person could slide beneath it.  In case you hadn't figured it out already, this means that while the zombies are distracted by eating Nick, Glenn can simply slide under the dumpster and hide, killing any zombies that try to get under the dumpster with him.

#### Links to relevant information:

> From the site "Spoiling Dead Fans", [this thread](http://thespoilingdeadfans.tumblr.com/page/2) features audio of Steven Yeun, who plays Glenn, rehearsing lines for scenes we haven't seen yet, as well as [video](https://www.facebook.com/matthew.maggio.9/videos/o.164502373704909/1702012080018913/?type=2&theater) of Glenn sliding under the dumpster.  It also contains all the information I mentioned in the previous blockquote.

#### Photos of filming of scenes from still-unreleased episodes:

Photo #1:

> [image]

Photo #2:

> [image]

Photo #3:

> [image]

Photo #4:

> [image]

#### How do we know that these pictures show filming for as-yet-unreleased episodes?

> Because they include a character named Jesus, who is well known to comic book fans, but who hasn't appeared on the show yet (he's the guy with long hair wearing a ski cap).  In the comic books, he was introduced at a time shortly after where we are now on the show, but he might appear before or after Glenn is found.

#### Update:  New photos:

Photo #5:

> [image]

Photo #6:

> [image]

Photo #7:

> [image]

What these photos show us:

> Filming for episode 7, on location at the dumpster in Hampton, back in June.  Enid, wearing the same clothes we last saw her in at the end of episode 2.  Glenn/Steven Yeun hiding in the bushes.

Photo #8:

> [image]

Photo #9:

> [image]

What these photos show us:

> Steven Yeun on set and filming... On October 28 and 29.

#### Conclusion based on clear cut evidence:

> The clear cut evidence makes the answer absolutely clear:  **No, Glenn is very definitely *not* dead.**

---

## Speculation on what we'll see in episode 7:

> Glenn has hidden under the dumpster.  Enid, who disappeared at the end of episode 2, will appear in town.  She will see the zombies surrounding the dumpster, realize someone is trapped under it, and lure the zombies away.  Glenn will emerge, then try to reunite with Enid.  He will eventually make his way back to Alexandria and resume "life as normal", whatever "normal" means in the TWD universe.

---

*The Spoiling Dead Fans*' theory:

> The site, linked above, has some apparently conflicting reports about what is going on.  The one thing they are absolutely sure of is that Glenn is definitely not dead.  However, they have received reports that insist that the guts we saw the zombies eating during the "death scene" were clearly supposed to be Glenn's, not Nick's, and that Nick landed somewhere near Glenn, but not on top of him. Some of the people who run the site have therefore come to believe that the "death scene" was actually a dream or fantasy sequence, and didn't really happen.  I don't buy this, because it just doesn't sound like *TWD*'s style.

### Interesting note:

> You might have noticed that Steven Yeun's name was missing from the opening credits in episode 4.  This is certainly part of the producers' attempt to fool us into believing that Glenn is dead.  However, when other characters died, the names of the actors who played them remained in the credits for the rest of the season.  The fact that they want us to think that they changed the rules in this case makes their ruse ineffective. As strange as it might sound, if Glenn was really dead, Yeun's name would still be in the credits.  His name is missing, so Glenn is alive.

---

### Rumor:

> Steven Yeun is [said](http://www.celebdirtylaundry.com/2015/the-walking-dead-season-6-spoilers-glenns-return-episode-details-steven-yeuns-name-missing-from-twd-credits/) to have [recently](http://www.designntrend.com/articles/63633/20151031/the-walking-dead-season-6-spoilers-10-reasons-steven-yeun-glenn-may-not-be-dead-yet.htm) signed a new [contract](http://screencrush.com/the-walking-dead-glenn-lives-negan/) with AMC to remain on the show.  Why would he do so if he had just been killed off?

### Update:

> At the end of S6E6, Daryl heard a voice on the radio cry out for help.  As we see in the photo below, Glenn had a radio when he was atop the dumpster, and he obviously needs help now, so it makes sense to assume it was him.

Related Photo:

> [image]

Comment: Haha, you're right! Woops!
And I agree on your take.

Comment: +1 I have never seen so many spoiler blocks in one post... And I am too scared to reveal them :-(

Comment: I'm really not sure what the status of this answer should be now that the answer is plainly known as of s06e07.

Comment: It’s 2021 and the suspense is killing me: So is Glenn dead or not?!? 

Answer (score 0):

No he did not. It was really Nickolas who had died. When they fell of the the dumpster Glen landed first then Nickolas landed on top of Glen so the walkers ate Nickolas which gave Glen time to throw the dead body off of him and got under the dumpster. And that is why Glen is still alive.